# Get Google Sheet by ID or Name, but not from active sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Can i get this script to work from sheet id or sheet name

This script works when i use the active spreadsheet but i want it to get it from the spreadsheet name or the sheet id. If i add .getSheetByName("Test") to line 2 it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null"

i am running the script from the sheet named "test" and there is a value in cell a1

Thanks in advance for the help

````
function CheckPrice() {
var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
if (priceRange < 10){
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
var message = 'This is your Alert email!';
var subject = 'Your Google Spreadsheet Alert';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change twice `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mySheetName')`

For instance

```
function CheckPrice() { 
  var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test').getRange("A1").getValue();  
  // get value from cell a1 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
  if (priceRange < 10){ 
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Test').getRange("A2"); 
    // get email from cell a2 
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue(); 
    // Send Alert Email. 
    var message = 'This is your Alert email!';  
    var subject = priceRange + " %up"; 
    // adds cell value to subject 
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); }  
}
```

Comment: I have tested in my own spreadsheet and it works fine ! did you give authorizations to google? Can you share your spreadsheet?

Comment: Your suggestion is right, it works if i try `function CheckPrice() { 
  var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1").getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  if (priceRange < 10){
    ui.alert('lower than 10');
    }
}` but when i replace the alert to an email it give me an error on `var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('hul').getRange("A1").getValue()`

Comment: you must authorize Google to send email on your behalf

Comment: i know, rewrote it and it works idk why`function CheckPrice() { 
  var priceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A1").getValue();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 if (priceRange < 10){
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange("A2"); // get email from cell a2
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'This is your Alert email!'; 
var subject = priceRange + " %up"; // adds cell value to subject
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
}`